# error when deleting view

Tags: views

when I try to delete a view from the views module, I receive the following error:
[error_1](http://www.vogelgesang-consulting.de/sites/default/files/error%20drupal.jpg)

Trying to save a new view shows this:
[error_2](http://www.vogelgesang-consulting.de/sites/default/files/error%202.jpg)

Any idea how to fix this?

I also cannot delete the view manually as my phpadmin tells me that there is an error and that I have to configure session.save_path... but I cannot find any file named session.save_path on my server.

Please let me know if you ever had this errors and if you know how to fix this. I invested 50 hrs to develop new functionality and I cannot risk the website goes down for days...

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: 1) The first of the two errors you link to could not be causing deletion to fail. Something else must be happening as well. Have you checked the logs? 2) What  if you try to create a new View with a different name? 3) Please don't link to images outside of the site. Preferably just copy the error messages into the question, or attach the images to the it.

Comment: I am not allowed to post images as my profile has not the correct status.. so for now I linked them through my website. where can I check the logs? trying to enable the database logging shows:

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'usr_web181_2.watchdog' doesn't exist: INSERT INTO {watchdog} (uid, type, message, variables, severity, link, location, referer, hostname, timestamp)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've got some pretty serious problems here.

The fact that you can't use PHPMyAdmin because of the `session.save_path` setting (which is in php.ini by the way, it's not file name) would suggest that something on your server has changed. At a guess I'd say your web server no longer has write access to the session folder, but without seeing the full error message it's hard to say.

The fact that the you can't enable the db log module is also quite worrying. That module defines the `watchdog` table upon install so the fact that it's missing might suggest Drupal is having problems creating database tables.

The best advice I can give is to get a local version of the site up and running, with permissions for files/databases set up in a way you know is correct, and see if you still have problems.

If you do, then you know that the problem is somewhere else and you should start methodically disabling and uninstalling modules until you can narrow down the culprit.

If you don't, then you know the problem is with the live server configuration.

Comment: This morning I was able to log in to PHPMYAdmin and I ran a repair on all tables. Post to that, I deactivated unused modules and deleted them. Deleted the content auf  "semaphore" and "sessions" table, deleted cache and tried again to work with views. WORKING! Was able to delete and to create views.. perfect!!!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted, that sounded like a nightmare for a minute there!